# Выполнение атомарных операций по подписке

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Передо мной стоит задача реализовать возможность выполнения атомарных операций для подписки на удаленный сервис. Сервис в последующем будет присылать извещения на открытый порт.

Таких подписок может быть 1 и более.

Собственно ищу красивое и расширяемое в будущем решение.
Мне нужно выполнить подписки на все сервисы одновременно. Если произошел сбой при подписке, то нужно отписаться от хостов, с которыми соединение было установлено, до возникновения сбоя.
Своего рода атомарная операция с возможностью отката.
Можете посоветовать, какие паттерны для этого лучше применить?

Comment: Из вопроса вообще ничего не понятно. Буду удивлен, если на него будет дан хоть какой-то ответ.

Comment: Не могли бы вы, как нибудь переформулировать сказанное? Подкрепить примерами или, если это необходимо, диаграммами.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте построить логику на основе паттерна Observer
[Как пример](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)